# Boost thread example show error it's cannot matching function for call to 'boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I'm initialized thread on main function when created namspace `multithread_init` in order to push `set_multihthread` class to namespace. Why after declared `boost::thread` it's not matching function for call `boost::thread  t(smulti.thread)`?

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>


#ifndef MULTITHREAD_INIT_HPP_
#define MULTITHREAD_INIT_HPP_
namespace multithread_init{
    class set_multithread{
    private:
        //t;
    public:
        void thread(){
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                wait(1);
                std::cout<<" thread i value : "<<i<<std::endl;
            }
        }

        void wait(int seconds)
        {
          boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds));
        }

//      void multi_case(){
//          t.join();
//          boost::thread  t(thread);
//      }

    };
}

#endif /* MULTITHREAD_INIT_HPP_ */
```

main file follow as below.

```
int main()
{

    /*thread */
    multithread_init::set_multithread smulti;
    boost::thread  t(smulti.thread);
    t.join();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a member function that way. You need to bind it to the object

```
boost::thread  t(boost::bind(&multithread_init::set_multithread::thread, &smulti));
```

Comment: Why we using `boost::bind(...)` with threads? for bind with threads?

Comment: @chatsiri: no, bind has nothing to do with threads. You just need to bind a member function to an object on which that member function must be called. The syntax you used is valid in C# not in C++

Comment: useless T_T (at least on qt4 4.8.2 with qt creator under linux mint)

Comment: I don't think you need the bind expression. The thread's constructor should know how to deal with the bind's arguments directly.